Bar chart not updated when button is selected for a plotly python graph
Below plotly code renders bar graph with buttons to select either stack or group style. But chart does not updates style when a selection is made on button. How do I fix this:
fig1 = go.Figure()

x  = temp_df.index
y1 = temp_df['Sales'].astype(float) # Sales Column
y2 = temp_df['Expenses'].astype(float) # Expenses Column
y3 = temp_df['Operating Profit'].astype(float) # Expenses Column
y4 = temp_df['Net Profit'].astype(float) # Expenses Column

fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y1, name='Sales', marker_color ="#4287f5"))
fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y2, name='Expenses', marker_color ="#f06969"))
fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y3, name='Operating Profit', marker_color ="#469984"))
fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y4, name='Net Profit', marker_color ="#53c24f"))

fig1.update_layout(
        title='<b>QoQ Performance</b>',
        xaxis_title='Quarter',
        yaxis_title='Rupees in Cr.')

updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type = "buttons",
            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args=['barmode', 'Group'],
                    label="Group",
                    method="update",
                ),
                dict(
                    args=["barmode", "stack"],
                    label="Stack",
                    method="update"
                )
            ]) 
        ),
    ]

fig1.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig1.show()



Reference Dataframe. Index is Quarter.



Quarter
Sales
Expenses
Operating Profit
Net Profit




q1
674.3
529.47
144.83
48.81


q2
634.32
498.08
136.24
45.91


q3
338.17
265.54
72.63
24.48


q4
1209.9
949.99
259.86
87.57




If you want a quick fix then just change method="update" to method="relayout".
Also, find an optimized version of code below,
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig1 = go.Figure()


data = {
    'Quarter': ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4'],
    'Sales': [674.3, 634.32, 338.17, 1209.9],
    'Expenses': [529.47, 498.08, 265.54, 949.99],
    'Operating Profit': [144.83, 136.24, 72.63, 259.86],
    'Net Profit': [48.81, 45.91, 24.48, 87.57]
}
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = temp_df.index
y1 = temp_df['Sales'].astype(float)
y2 = temp_df['Expenses'].astype(float)
y3 = temp_df['Operating Profit'].astype(float)
y4 = temp_df['Net Profit'].astype(float)

fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y1, name='Sales', marker_color="#4287f5"))
fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y2, name='Expenses', marker_color="#f06969"))
fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y3, name='Operating Profit', marker_color="#469984"))
fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y4, name='Net Profit', marker_color="#53c24f"))

fig1.update_layout(
    title='<b>QoQ Performance</b>',
    xaxis_title='Quarter',
    yaxis_title='Rupees in Cr.')

updatemenus=[
    dict(
        type="buttons",
        buttons=list([
            dict(
                label="Group",
                method="relayout",
                args=[{"barmode": "group"}]
            ),
            dict(
                label="Stack",
                method="relayout",
                args=[{"barmode": "stack"}]
            )
        ])
    )
]
    
fig1.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig1.show()

